# How to select rows where given data appear in more than one row in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table of transactions with client id and item id, what I need is to select only those transactions where client bought more than one thing.

```
  transaction_id | client_id | item_id
  ---------------------------------------
  1              | 1         |  10
  2              | 1         |  11
  3              | 2         |  11
  4              | 3         |  11
  5              | 4         |  12
  6              | 4         |  12
```

So here that would be transaction ids: 1,2,5,6 , so in other words to return such rows where client ID (here 1, 4 - but I still need these 4 rows, not distinct) is appearing more than once in table. Is there a way to perform that in one query without going back to programming language ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction t1
WHERE client_id in ( SELECT client_id 
                     FROM transaction t2
                     GROUP BY client_id 
                     HAVING count(*) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join the table with itself

```
SELECT t1.transaction_id, t2.transaction_id, t1.client_id
FROM transaction t1, transaction t2
WHERE t1.transaction_id <> t2.transaction_id AND t1.client_id = t2.client_id
```

Comment: Note, by the way, that implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, syntax: Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this method, to select higher numbers of items in transaction ?

Comment: To generalize you could say `select distinct t1.*`. The inner join would take care of finding at least one match where `client_id`s match but `transaction_id`s do not. Juan's approach is better in part because the cartesian product can grow to be very large and the duplication of rows is the reason you need `distinct`.